# Using ADO.NET and SQL Server, how to fetch datarows of two tables at once (snapshot)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, snapshot

Using ADO.NET, is it possible to fetch datarows from two tables at once ?

As it is now, it's done in two steps :

```
DataTable log = GetDataTable("select * from Log");
DataTable logDetail = GetDataTable("select * from LogDetail");
```

The problem is that data can change between the two calls (eg : we fetch all the log records, meanwhile some new logs and details are created in DB, then we fetch details : some details wont have associated logs).

A possible solution is to do a single query with a join between the two tables :

```
select *
from Log 
inner join LogDetail on Log.Id = LogDetail.RefLog
```

Now there is only one call, but there is another problem : log data is duplicated for each log detail which means there will be lot more data transfered (these two tables are already very big)

Is there another solution

Comment: you can send 2 statements to server. Something like: `"select * from Log; select * from LogDetail"`: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6897bc/processing-multiple-queries-with-single-sqlcommand-in-ado-ne/

Comment: It is possible, but you have to specify clearly what you want to fetch. Should the results be in the same set (in this case there should be an association) or the results would be in different data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use [SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

If yes, then [Zohar Peled's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31969309/623190) answer can be extended by transaction:

```
var ds = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);

    command.Transaction = transaction;
    command.CommandText = "select * from Log; select * from LogDetail";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Data modifications made by other transactions after the start of the current transaction are not visible to statements executing in the current transaction. The effect is as if the statements in a transaction get a snapshot of the committed data as it existed at the start of the transaction. ([from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Yes using SNAPSHOT is possible. Seems the best possible answer so far. Let me check this and i will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dear if you want to have them in one query this can be achieved in many ways, I see you're using ADO.NET so you need a SQL Query. Now you have two tables and you're having a problem that a "Log" record may have more than one "LogDetails" record.

So simply if you want to make one SQL Query you can achieve this by:

```
SELECT *
FROM LogDetails
INNER JOIN Log on LogDetails.RefLog = Log.Id
```

You'll get a list of LogDetails Object and after that you can group them by "Log" fields (e.g., Id, Name, ..etc.) by the end of this you'll have a list of Log objects and every object containing List of LogDetails. Hope that helped ^^

Comment: This is basically what i suggest in the OP. Issue is that both Log and LogDetails are already very big , this will duplicate `Log` records for each `LogDetail` thus making even more data.

Comment: You have to choose either doing what i've mentioned if you want to retrieve all LogDetails for each Log with one query. The other way is to make a subquery for each distnct LogDetails RefLog [FK] .. which retrieve the proper Log but that wont be made as a single query ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can send both queries to the sql server in a single command (as mentioned by Khanh TO in the comments) and just fill a `dataset`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Log; select * from LogDetail", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

This will result with `ds` having 2 data tables - one for each query.

**Note:** Code was written directly here and not tested, there might be some mistakes.

Comment: As a note this does answer the question but will not always negate the issue you are facing. The two select statements are separate so data can still be added in between the two occurring, however the issue will probably be limited because it does not have to return back through ado before calling the second query.

Comment: @bonyjoe : i understand what you mean. What Zohar suggested is a kind of tradeoff. I was wondering if there was something that would prevent data to change between the two selects : eg : `lock Log, LogDetail; select * from Log; select * from LogDetail; unlock Log, LogDetail;`